# browsers built-in public key

Tags: security

while searching about security issues i hear this 
"Browsers and the JDK itself come with built-in certificates 
and their public keys from several CAs"..

Can any one help me to find out the process to identify browsers built-in
public key..
Is my question reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a pristine new install of the browser in question.
2. Use the browser Preferences/Options menus to find the list of pre-installed CA certificates:

   - On my Firefox 3.6.15 browser that is at Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Encryption->View Certificates->Authorities
   - On my Chromium it's at Preferences->Under the Hood->Security->Manage certificates->Authorities

Any other browser should be somewhat similar in this respect, although the list of pre-installed CA will probably differ when it comes to some of the more minor CAs.